# Any Wordpress Plugin Can Sorting Alphabet for Team Page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing one website based on Wordpress. In Lawyers Page I need to sort People following Alphabet and Categories.
I can't sort by Alphabet following Name.

I need one plugin and sort Alphabet like this image:
[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbb7o.png)

I can accept buy premium plugin but budget are $50 for that plugin.
Please suggest me some plugins that can do it.

Comment: try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! Let me post on that page